# Hibernate Multiple Association Issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, associations

I have **3** entities. ***User,Project and Role.***
A user can be assigned to multiple projects with some roles.
A user **GEORGE** can have **ADMIN** role on **PROJECT-A** and **MANAGER** role on **PROJECT-B**. How can I map these entities using bi-directional association.

*The relation can be described in following way.

A USER can have many projects through a role.

A role can be assigned to 0 or more projects for a specific User.*

Is it possible with a **JOIN-TABLE**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to introduce a fourth entity (let's call it `Right`), which tells that a specific user has a specific role on a specific project. You will thus end with the following associations :

- One User has Many Rights
- One Role has Many Rights
- One Project has Many Rights

The RIght entity will be mapped to a table having three foreign keys (to user, role and project), and the tuple `(userId, projectId, roleId)` should be unique.

You'll need to use dedicated queries (or Java methods) to find the roles of a user for a project :

```
public class User {
    // ...
    public Set<Role> getRolesForProject(Project project) {
        Set<Role> result = new HashSet<Role>();
        for (Right right : rights) {
            if (right.getProject().equals(project)) {
                result.add(right.getRole());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

or, in HQL :

```
select role from Right right 
inner join right.role role 
where right.user = :user 
and right.project = :project
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user can not have multiple roles within a project, just map @ManyToOne Projects to your User and have the Role relation reside in your Project class.

```
class User {
     @OneToMany (mappedBy = "projects")
     List<Project> projects;
     [...]
}

class Project {
     @ManyToOne
     User user;
     Role userRole;
     [...]
}
```

This does however neglect the possibility to have multiple users assigned to one project, which you didn't state but i believe should be a possibility.

Just look up Hibernate Annotations an Bi-directional (BI-WINNING!) on google or your favorite search engine.

Didn't really go into detail here, seeing that OP only has 29% accept rate..

cheers